# Выполнение скрипта только в одной вкладке

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как по умному реализовать выполнение скрипта (javascript) только в одной вкладке?
Тоесть, если открыта страница, на ней выполняется функция. Если открыть в этот же момент другую вкладку с этой же страницей, то функция выполнятся не будет.
Если закрыть первую, то во второй должно заработать.

Answer (score 2):

Вконтакте есть реализация аудиопроигрывателя по такой схеме, т.е. проигрывается музыка только в одной вкладке, в остальных стоит пауза, подробнее можно прочитать http://habrahabr.ru/post/153937/. Как я понял надо надо хранить идентификатор окна в LocalStorage, при закрытии вкладки поймать событие закрытия и уведомить в LocalStorage что вкладка неактивна, тогда вторая вкладка должна перехватить это событие и записать свой идентификатор в LocalStorage.

Comment: У меня была мысль на счет этого, но не поучилось отловить закрытие вкладки.